# Ruby regex keep the first instance of pattern and substitute/remove the rest

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string that contains a certain word pattern repeatedly. How can I keep the first occurrence, remove if it is a certain case, and substitute the rest of the pattern if it is a certain case?

```
rocket = "Meowth, that's right!!! Prepare for trouble meowth, and make it double. MEOWTH ftw!!!"
```

I want to keep the first instance of `"meowth"`, case insensitive. The rest of `"meowth"` instance: if it is spelled all caps, it will be replaced with string `"team rocket"`. Other than that, it will be removed.

```
rocket.gsub(/meowth/i, 'team rocket')
```

The code above replaces all `"meowth"` string instances (case insensitive). How can I keep the first instance and substitute/remove the rest of the instance?

Desired output:

```
rocket = "Meowth, that's right!!! Prepare for trouble, and make it double. team rocket ftw!!!"
```

Comment: Is the first instance always at the start of the string?

Comment: Correct. My apologies, I wasn't clear. First instance means anytime you see `"meowth"` occur first in the string (case insensitive), even if it spelled MEOWTH, if it is first, it is left as is. Substitution/ removal happens after first occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first occurrence is at the start of the string, you may use a negative lookahead `(?!\A)` or lookbehind `(?<!\A)` at the start of the pattern to exclude the matches at the start of the string:

```
rocket = "Meowth, that's right!!! Prepare for trouble meowth, and make it double. MEOWTH ftw!!!"
rocket.gsub(/(?!\A)\s*(meowth)/i) { $1.upcase == $1 ? ' team rocket' : '' }
# => Meowth, that's right!!! Prepare for trouble, and make it double. team rocket ftw!!!
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/Z7j2WU)

If the first instance of the word can be anywhere inside the string, not just at the start of the string, use

```
rocket.gsub(/(?:\G(?!\A)|\A.*?meowth).*?\K\s*(meowth)/mi) { 
          $1.upcase == $1 ? ' team rocket' : '' 
}
```

See [another Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/hKznVQ).

**NOTE**: to match `meowth` as a whole word, enclose it with word boundaries: `/(?!\A)\s*\b(meowth)\b/`.

**Details**:

- `(?!\A)` - at the current position, there should be no start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(meowth)` - Group 1 capturing `meowth` (case-insensitively, due to `/i` modifier)

Or,

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\A.*?meowth)` - matches a location after a successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or a substring from the string start (`\A`) till the first occurrence of `meowth` (as `.*?` match any 0+ chars *as few times as possible*)
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first
- `\K` - omit the matched text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(meowth)` -  `meowth` (group 1).

Inside the block, the captured value is checked for being ALLCAPS with `.upcase`, and if it is, the value is replaced with `team rocket`, esle, removed.

Comment: In case you wonder if it is possible to use a pure regex solution to replace words from the second occurrence if not at the string start, see [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/YYEKzk).

Comment: Hi Wiktor! Thanks for the quick response, but how can I make the non all-caps removed? My apologies if it wasn't clear. Only `MEOWTH` gets replaced with `team rocket`; any other occurrence of meowth besides the first one: Meowth, meOwth, meowth, &c. that is not all caps (MEOWTH) need to be removed. See desired output.
Thanks! In your case, you have `Prepare for trouble team rocket, and...`, how can I make it `Prepare for trouble, and ...`.

Comment: Doesn't this require the first `meowth` to be the first word as well?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a complex regex for this, just pass a block:

```
str.gsub(/meowth/i).with_index do |w, i|
  if i != 0 && w == 'MEOWTH'
    w = 'team rocket'
  elsif i != 0
    w = ''
  end

  w
end
```